# Signup with Facebook JavaScript without a Facebook account

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been working with the Facebook JavaScript SDK recently for user signups, I've noticed if I use the system to login to an existing Facebook account it works fine but if I have to create a Facebook account it fails. I realise I'm a bit sparse on details here but I noticed it also fails on the Spotify website, is it even possible to use the JavaScript SDK for signups if the user doesn't have a Facebook account and has to create one? I realise if you don't have a Facebook account already you're unlikely to want to use that functionality but just wanted to see if it really doesn't work in that scenario? Or if it's just me and Spotify not implementing it right.

You can create the Facebook account then click the signup button on my website again and login with your now existing Facebook account and that will work fine, it just involved having to click the button a second time.

Comment: I’d say that’s probably rather a Facebook problem, and not one of specific implementation by either you or Spotify ... You can’t do more than send the user to the login flow, what happens then is out of your hands. You could perhaps try and check if that works any different with the server-side login flow, maybe that is able to handle this better than the JS SDK; if the issue is important enough for you. (If it works after the user starts the process a second time, I would probably not invest too much effort here - likely what the average user tends to do anyway if something “didn’t work” ...)

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the response, it certainly looks like it's a Facebook issue rather than an implementation problem on my end or Spotify, even Disqus has the same issue.